# AnyChart Template: How can I set the colour of a column only once?

Tags: javascript, anychart

I am using AnyChart and am trying to set the chart to have green and Red columns. Right now I have to set the colour on every column. Is there a way to set it for all?

What I am doing:

```
var data = anychart.data.set([
                ["04/24/2022", 2, 6, "#ab0000", "#009933"],
                ["04/25/2022", 3, 4, "#ab0000", "#009933"],
                ["04/26/2022", 4, 2, "#ab0000", "#009933"],
                ["04/27/2022", 5, 2, "#ab0000", "#009933"],
                ["04/28/2022", 5, 2, "#ab0000", "#009933"]
            ]);
```

Complete Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>JavaScript Bar Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.0/js/anychart-base.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="anychart-embed-samples-bct-stacking-02" class="anychart-embed anychart-embed-samples-bct-stacking-02">
        <script
            src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-base.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-exports.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-ui.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
        <div id="ac_style_samples-bct-stacking-02" style="display:none;">
            html, body, #container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }
        </div>
        <script>(function () {
                function ac_add_to_head(el) {
                    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                    head.insertBefore(el, head.firstChild);
                }
                function ac_add_link(url) {
                    var el = document.createElement('link');
                    el.rel = 'stylesheet'; el.type = 'text/css'; el.media = 'all'; el.href = url;
                    ac_add_to_head(el);
                }
                function ac_add_style(css) {
                    var ac_style = document.createElement('style');
                    if (ac_style.styleSheet) ac_style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
                    else ac_style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
                    ac_add_to_head(ac_style);
                }
                ac_add_link('https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/css/anychart-ui.min.css?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4');
                ac_add_style(document.getElementById("ac_style_samples-bct-stacking-02").innerHTML);
                ac_add_style(".anychart-embed-samples-bct-stacking-02{width:600px;height:450px;}");
            })();</script>
        <div id="container"
            style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;border:1px solid">
        </div>
        <script>
            anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

                // create a data set
                var data = anychart.data.set([
                    ["04/24/2022", 2, 6, "#ab0000", "#009933"],
                    ["04/25/2022", 3, 4, "#ab0000", "#009933"],
                    ["04/26/2022", 4, 2, "#ab0000", "#009933"],
                    ["04/27/2022", 5, 2, "#ab0000", "#009933"],
                    ["04/28/2022", 5, 2, "#ab0000", "#009933"]
                ]);

                // map the data
                var seriesData_1 = data.mapAs({ x: 0, value: 1, fill: 3 });
                var seriesData_2 = data.mapAs({ x: 0, value: 2, fill: 4 });

                // create a chart
                var chart = anychart.column();

                chart.xScroller(true);

                /* enable the percent stacking mode
                on the default primary value scale*/
                chart.yScale().stackMode("percent");

                // set the tick interval on the value scale
                chart.yScale().ticks().interval(20);

                // create column series
                chart.column(seriesData_1);
                chart.column(seriesData_2);

                // configure labels on the x-axis
                chart.xAxis().title("Date");

                // configure labels on the y-axis
                chart.yAxis().labels().format("{%value}%");
                chart.yAxis().title("Down Percentage");

                // configure tooltips
                chart.tooltip().format("{%yPercentOfCategory}{decimalsCount:2}%");

                // set the chart title
                chart.title("Wifi Up Percentage");

                // set the container id
                chart.container("container");

                // initiate drawing the chart
                chart.draw();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am looking for a way to not need to copy the colours over and over. Does anyone know how I could format the fill colour to be only in the column data?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to solve your problem with AnyChart.

You can [preconfigure colors with AnyChart Palettes.](https://docs.anychart.com/Appearance_Settings/Palettes)

```
// apply a palette to a chart
chart.palette(["#ab0000", "#009933"]);
```

Feel free to explore [how to apply palettes](https://playground.anychart.com/bIMB3ifr) in the playground.